# Pagination not working for ACF Query on front-page.php

Tags: wordpress, pagination, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the following query based on the ACF documentation. For some reason, the pagination isn't working. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? The pagination code is working fine on an archive.php page.

front-page.php

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'    => 6,
    'post_type'     => 'airdrop',

    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'airdrop_type',
            'value'     => array('Airdrop'),
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part('airdrops/full-width'); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php html5wp_pagination(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

pagination code in functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'html5wp_pagination');

function html5wp_pagination()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a plugin may not be the best solution but I ended up using WP-PageNavi which allows wp_query. This worked for me and solved the problem.

Documentation can be found here: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html

Answer (score 0):

check this
[Pagination_Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

And  http://prntscr.com/kt47rs
You don't need use add_action('init','...') function for pagination.
and use calling function like : `html5wp_pagination($the_query );`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried changing 'paged' to 'page' and changed html5wp_pagination(); to html5wp_pagination($the_query ); with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, replace with this

```
 function html5wp_pagination()
    {
        global $the_query;
        $big = 999999999;
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
            'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
        ));
    }
```

Comment: This has worked BUT I need it to direct to /airdrops/page/2 instead of /page/2 if that makes sense? You can see a working example here: http://airdropvillage.io/

Comment: You can't use Wordpress default pagination funtion here 
Then you need to create custom function :
1) $tp = get total post count
2) $ppp = per page post
3) make 'for'  loop with pass require parameter and add cusom link as you require